# I am trying to upload the document from my site to Google Docs using Zend Gdata library, but it gives below error

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, zend-gdata

**I am trying to upload the document from my site to Google Docs using Zend Gdata library, but it gives below error.**
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 Inconsistent repeating query parameter '

Thanks in Advance and please ignore my english errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "bug" in Zend_Gdata_Docs with the mimetype.
If you are using a temporary file and the filename as the title it will not auto-magically pull the mimetype for you. It tries to pull the mimetype based on the fileLocation extension which does not exist on a temporary file.

I made a class that works for me, rather than updating the Zend class.
It is called [ConvertDoc](http://blog.artistandesigns.com/2011/02/zendgdata-lacks-document-download.html) because I wanted to be able to [upload a spreadsheet and download as csv.](http://blog.artistandesigns.com/2011/02/zendgdata-lacks-document-download.html)

What you really need is this...

```
    // get mimetype from original file name
    $filenameParts = explode('.', $originalFileName);
    $fileExtension = end($filenameParts);
    $mimeType = Zend_Gdata_Docs::lookupMimeType($fileExtension);
```

And pass the $mimetype instead of null.